# Puppet Enterprise for Windows Fails to Run

Tags: puppet

I have the following error trying to run the Puppet Enterprise for Windows.

```
Faulting application name: ruby.exe, version: 1.8.7.370, time stamp: 0x4fede15f
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afc9
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x00014159
Faulting process id: 0x9e4
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce00a0586d444c
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet Enterprise\sys\ruby\bin\ruby.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ac79500b-6c93-11e2-bda6-000c2947d060
```

UAC is disabled
Firewall is Off

Answer (score 0):

I got the debug Windows Installer. My mistake